# How to argue Existence of Unique solution of an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that there exists a unique solution for this given IVP without solving? Just mere argument.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2y\sqrt{1-x^2}}, \qquad y(0)=3$$

I'm having problems with this kind of question because we're not taught of proving without solving. Please help.

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf).

Comment: If $f(x,y)$ satisfies Lipschitz's condition

Answer (score 2):

Any solution has to be monotonically increasing and $f(x,y)$ is for $y\in[3,\infty)$ Lipschitz-continuous.

More generally one could argue that $f(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable in $y$ and thus a local solution exists and is unique.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the Local Exsitence Theorem which is given by:[image]

$(3.1)$ $y'=f(t,y)$

$(3.2)$ $y(t_0)=y_0$

$(3.6)$ $|f(t,y)|<M$ and $|\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,y)|<K$

$(3.8)$ $\phi_{j+1}(t)=y_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(s,\phi_j(s))ds$ $j=0,1,2,.....$